# How to pass route values to controllers in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am struggling to understand something that I am sure one of you will be able to easily explain. I am somewhat new to MVC so please bear with me.

I have created a controller that handles all of the work involved with connecting to the Twitter API and processing the returned JSON into HTML.

```
Route::get('/about', 'TwitterController@getTweets');
```

I then use:

```
return View::make('templates.about', array('twitter_html' => $twitter_html ))
```

Within my controller to pass the generated HTML to my view and everything works well.

My issue is that I have multiple pages that I use to display a different Twitter user's tweets on each page. What I would like to do is pass my controller an array of values (twitter handles) which it would then use in the API call.  What I do not want to have to do is have a different Controller for each user group. If I set `$twitter_user_ids` within my Controller I can use that array to pull the tweets, but I want to set the array and pass it into the Controller somehow. I would think there would be something like

```
Route::get('/about', 'TwitterController@getTweets('twitter_id')');
```

But that last doesn't work.

I believe that my issue is related to variable scope somehow, but I could be way off.

Am I going down the wrong track here? How do I pass my Controllers different sets of data to produce different results?

## EDIT - More Info

Markus suggested using Route Parameters, but I'm not sure that will work with what I am going for.  Here is my specific use case.

I have an about page that will pull my tweets from Twitters API and display them on the page.
I also have a "Tweets" page that will pull the most recent tweets from several developers accounts and display them.

In both cases I have $twitter_user_ids = array() with different values in the array.

The controller that I have built takes that array of usernames and accesses the API and generates HTML which is passed to my view.

Because I am working with an array (the second of which is a large array), I don't think that Route Parameters will work.

Thanks again for the help.  I couldn't do it without you all!

Comment: **+1 for your efforts on learning Laravel 4!**

Comment: You can pass arrays to route parameters. Try it and see if it works. This also sounds a little bit like Route Model Binding. Have a look at: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Hey Markus, I am working through this now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey Markus, I'm afraid I am still not following.  1: Is using the URI really the only way to pass parameters to your controller's?  I would hate to have to change my directory structure just to avoid code duplication. 2: How would you pass an array via Route Parameters?  How would I put an array in the URI?  I am pretty lost here...

Comment: _It looks like your design concept is a little messed up._ Show me some code from the controller you built that handles the twitter array you mentioned in your edit.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here's a quick tip:

Instead of

```
return View::make('templates.about', array('twitter_html' => $twitter_html ))
```

...use

```
return View::make('templates.about', compact('twitter_html'))
```

This creates the $twitter_html automatically for you. Check it out in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php).

### Now to your problem:

You did the route part wrong. Try:

```
Route::get('/about/{twitter_id}', 'TwitterController@getTweets');
```

This passes the twitter_id param to your getTweets function.

Check out the Laravel Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand how using Route Parameters will work with my issue.  I am going to edit my original question to add more detail.

Comment: `I want to set the array and pass it into the Controller somehow` - The answer I provided covers exactly this. Have a look at the laravel docs. I provided the link in my answer. The param will be passed from the route to your controller. Work with the param like `public function getTweets($twitter_id) {...}`.